# Extract a global variable

Tags: python, executable

I'm trying to extact a global variable from an executable. Basically, I'm tryin to reverse an executable that put some python bytecode in a global variable and I'd like to extract it. I found out that the data is in the .data of the PE File, but I can't find a way to get it in all the data segments.
Any ideas?

Comment: @MaxenceHenneron: if it's a variable that can be found in the `.data` section that sounds to me like it's an initialized variable. What more than the part in the `.data` section do you need then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say you are trying to reverse an executable which stores some python bytecode in a variable, it means probably the executable [*embeds python*](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html). If the code is likely to be executed at some point of time, you can use a debugger.

Set a breakpoint on **[PyEval_EvalFrameEx](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/veryhigh.html?highlight=pyeval_evalframeex#PyEval_EvalFrameEx)** .

It has a prototype of `PyObject* PyEval_EvalFrameEx(PyFrameObject *f, int throwflag)`

The first parameter `PyFrameObject` has the following structure.

```
typedef struct _frame {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    struct _frame *f_back;  /* previous frame, or NULL */
    PyCodeObject *f_code;   /* code segment */
    PyObject *f_builtins;   /* builtin symbol table (PyDictObject) */
    PyObject *f_globals;    /* global symbol table (PyDictObject) */
    PyObject *f_locals;     /* local symbol table (any mapping) */
    PyObject **f_valuestack;    /* points after the last local */
    PyObject **f_stacktop;
    PyObject *f_trace;      /* Trace function */
    PyObject *f_exc_type, *f_exc_value, *f_exc_traceback;
    PyThreadState *f_tstate;
    int f_lasti;        /* Last instruction if called */
    int f_lineno;       /* Current line number */
    int f_iblock;       /* index in f_blockstack */
    PyTryBlock f_blockstack[CO_MAXBLOCKS]; /* for try and loop blocks */
    PyObject *f_localsplus[1];  /* locals+stack, dynamically sized */
} PyFrameObject;
```

The *third* member of `PyFrameObject` is `PyCodeObject`.

`PyCodeObject` has the following structure.

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    int co_argcount;        /* #arguments, except *args */
    int co_nlocals;     /* #local variables */
    int co_stacksize;       /* #entries needed for evaluation stack */
    int co_flags;       /* CO_..., see below */
    PyObject *co_code;      /* instruction opcodes */
    PyObject *co_consts;    /* list (constants used) */
    PyObject *co_names;     /* list of strings (names used) */
    PyObject *co_varnames;  /* tuple of strings (local variable names) */
    PyObject *co_freevars;  /* tuple of strings (free variable names) */
    PyObject *co_cellvars;      /* tuple of strings (cell variable names) */
    /* The rest doesn't count for hash/cmp */
    PyObject *co_filename;  /* string (where it was loaded from) */
    PyObject *co_name;      /* string (name, for reference) */
    int co_firstlineno;     /* first source line number */
    PyObject *co_lnotab;    /* string (encoding addr<->lineno mapping) */
    void *co_zombieframe;     /* for optimization only (see frameobject.c) */
} PyCodeObject;
```

The *sixth* member of the above structure is `co_code` . It is basically a `PyStringObject`. 
It has the following structure.

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD
    long ob_shash;
    int ob_sstate;
    char ob_sval[1];
} PyStringObject;
```

The `ob_sval` contains the bytecode you are after.
So once you hit `PyEval_EvalFrameEx` follow the structures in memory to get the bytecode.

Another thing to note is you need to know the layout of `PyObject_VAR_HEAD` and `PyObject_HEAD` to get the actual offsets. Refer to the [python source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3124790c07b4) for more information.